# Unknown NullPointerException in JdbcOdbcDriver.finalize() line: 96

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, nullpointerexception, jndi

I'm loading data sources via JNDI using:

JDK 1.6.0_31
Tomcat 6.0.30

When I launch the Eclipse (Indigo SR 2) debugger, it breaks on:

```
Daemon System Thread [Finalizer] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))   
    JdbcOdbcDriver.finalize() line: 96  
    Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Object) line: not available [native method]  
    Finalizer.runFinalizer() line: 83   
    Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer) line: 14    
    Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() line: 160
```

I'm really at a loss as to what is causing this. Further, it doesn't appear to affect my execution at all. My data sources are initialized and used as normal, and I'm getting all the results that I expect. From what I've read, this might be related to an Oracle driver issue?

myApp\META-INF\context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/conn" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="@url@" username="user" password="@password@"
    initialSize="4" maxActive="8" 
    defaultAutoCommit="false"
    accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
    testOnReturn="true"
    validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
    poolPreparedStatements="false"
    connectionProperties="SetBigStringTryClob=true"
    factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
/>
```

myApp\WEB-INF\web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>My DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/conn</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: Folks might want to see the JdbcOdbcDriver [source code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/jdbc/odbc/JdbcOdbcDriver.java.html) for reference.

Comment: @adarshr The link you gave seems to now point to spam/fishing (or my computer is infected?). I found [another link](http://j6a.ru/_jdbc_odbc_driver_8java_source.html) to it.

Comment: Which version of Oracle JDBC Driver do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually ended up ignoring this exception as it does not end execution. While I don't know the exact cause, it does not seem to be fatal.

Comment: I wish u had found an explanation for it, but nobody seems to understand it well..

Comment: This is very harmful answer since ignored exceptions in finalization method lead to memory leak.

Comment: @Gregory.K, I agree, but as you can see, no one else responded, and I never found the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you're missing a call to initialize(). That should fix a NPE to OdbcApi.

Answer (score -1):

I previously thought that this was the answer. I was wrong.

Finally I figured it out. I had some managed beans that were backed by a database. These managed beans were annotated @eager

When the server started the app from eclipse, they were instantiated and the tool went to the database to get the data. I had an exception thrown in the method from the database bean (a null pointer exception), and as a result, the connection to the database was being left open.

Somehow, the .metadata folder was buggered up and corrupted. I exited Eclipse. Then I went to the Eclipse workspace and copied the .metadata folder to my desktop to have a safe copy, then I deleted it in the workspace.

I re-started Eclipse. There were no projects. I imported them back in using Import > File System.

I had to fix the Build Path under the project properties and under the Window > Preferences, I had to reset the Tomcat Home. Voila, got rid of this super annoying problem.

That was the cause of the problem. Hope this helps someone.